# EWS Exchange Impersonate 2 or more users using one ExchangeService connection

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In order to avoid the Exchange Server limit RCAMaxConcurrency (0-100), I want to code a listener service (streamlistener) that can handle up to 5000 users using just one connection. I already have 200 test accounts and another account having impersonate rights over those 200 test accounts. 
If possible it would be nice to avoid switching around all accounts.

We already have the code and it works fine doing impersonation just to 1 user.

```
public void SuscribeToCalendar()
{
    // Set the email address of the account to get the appointment.
    service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "xxxxxxxxx");
    // Subscribe to streaming notifications in the Inbox. 
    StreamingSubscription streamingSubscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
        new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Calendar }, EventType.Created, EventType.Modified, EventType.Moved);

    // Create a streaming connection to the service object, over which events are returned to the client.
    // Keep the streaming connection open for 30 minutes.
    StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 30);
    connection.AddSubscription(streamingSubscription);
    connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
    connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
    connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: Hola Fernando, I really dont understand what you want to accomplish but look at my app and se ehow I use impersonation maybe this could give you an idea https://github.com/rojobo/EWSContactsSynchronization/blob/master/cContactsSynchronization.vb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RCAMaxConcurrency doesn't affect EWS it affect Outlook connections which use RPC to connect. What will affect EWS is EWSMaxConcurrency which has a much a lower value to 10 by default. (you would also get affected by EWSMaxSubscriptions which is 20).

The impersonation setting affect the header of the EWS request so you can't impersonate any more the one user per call so when creating a subscription you need one call per user you subscribing. You can group the Subscripting together into one connection with impersonation using the following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx .

The limitations with group is 200 users per group, given the amount of churn you have with subscriptions you don't really want any more the this. When your using impersonation the number of connections isn't an issue as long as you don't anchor ever group with the same mailbox.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Yes you really understood what Im looking for. Now my concern is, if exchange has all those throttling-limit-policies, then how can e.g. 1000 employees using smartphones listen to exchange notifications in a concurrent way? those 10, 20, 200 limits sounds too few.

Comment: Is there any way to consume EWS from mobile app, without coding a listener-service running at a server (between exchange and the mobile app)?

Comment: >> 1000 employees using smartphones listen to exchange notifications in a concurrent way?  the concurrency limit is per user so in that example its only one connection per device/user. The restriction is based on one user account can't have more the 10 concurrent connection open at once (there is no limits to number on concurrency connections at the Exchange server level which it seem is your assumption).  When your use impersonation that concurrency issue really goes away because the connection is charged to the user your impersonating.

Comment: You can use Streaming notifications on a mobile device okay the way they work is very similar to the Activesync. However I would generally go with a server based solution and then use notification hub (eg Azure notification hubs is one example) to do the push to the mobile devices. That simplifies the mobile application greatly and allows you scale across different mobile devices type without needing all the steaming logic implemented on each device and you have less worry about battery life issues that an inefficient streaming app could cause on a mobile device. (that's just imo)

Comment: The advantages of impersonating are: you dont need to know users passwords, and that by using 1 account you can impersonate up to 200-250 grouped accounts right? and this does not consume final-users connection limits. Then... 1 account with impersonation roll, can handle 200 final-user accounts per group per connection, since EWSMaxConcurrency is 10, this accout with impersonation roll can hangle 10x200=2000 final-user accounts. Then I will need 3 accounts with impersonation roll to handle 5000. Did I understood you well?

Comment: On the other hand.... we do need one ExchangeService per final-account. Why StreamingSubscriptionConnection has its own ExchangeService since all the StreamingSubscription that it has inside also has one ExchangeService.

Comment: No that isn't correct the Concurrency in charged against the X-Anchor mailbox which will be one of the Mailboxes in the Group. So you only need 1 account for impersonation and good grouping code for as many users as you want. Concurrency shouldn't be an issue with the Impersonation account.